# Repeat a column value

Tags: python, dataframe

I have input dataframe in below format

[image]

I want the output in below format

[image]

Input data for referance

```
import pandas as pd
dfno = pd.DataFrame({'Nodes':['A','B','C'], 'Connections': ['Za,Eb', 'Qa,Rb', 'La,Mb']})
```

I tried below code to convert each value of both rows into list and then adding to dataframe. But it did not work. Here character in connection columns are getting split.

```
for index, row in dfno.iterrows():
    node = str(row['Nodes'])
    connec = list(str(row['Connections']))
    print(node)
    print(connec)
```

How to do this?

Comment: You can refer [stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution here is with `explode`:

```
dfno.assign(Connections=dfno['Connections'].str.split(',')).explode('Connections')
```

Output:

```
  Nodes Connections
0     A          Za
0     A          Eb
1     B          Qa
1     B          Rb
2     C          La
2     C          Mb
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
dfno = pd.DataFrame({'Nodes':['A','B','C'], 'Connections': ['Za,Eb', 'Qa,Rb', 'La,Mb']})

for index, row in dfno.iterrows():
    node = str(row['Nodes'])
    connec = str(row['Connections']).split(',')
    print(node)
    print(connec)
```

Comment: can you give me full solution so i can accept? i want to explode 'nodes' for each value of 'connections'

Comment: @SoKu For loop is inefficient here, use regular pandas, like mine

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df["Connections"] = df["Connections"].str.split(",")
df = df.explode("Connections").reset_index(drop=True)
```

I hope that it can help you resolve the problem.